# PMS5003 ST - Humidity / Fog - modelling

Tags: esp8266

I am building a simple PM2.5 PM10 station based on PMS5003ST (Plantower) and ESP32 to measure the particles in the air and convert the readings to the Air Quality Index. Everything works fine, but i have noticed that when there is a lot of fog - the readings are realy realy HIGH - (they jump even 300%).

From what i read in the PMS5003ST documentation - the particle sensor is very sensitive when there is a fog - meaning, it can count the fog particles too.

[PMS5003ST](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arduinolibrary/DFRobot_SEN0233_Air_Quality_Monitor/master/PMS5003ST%20series%20data%20manua_English_V2.6%20.pdf)

Questions:

1. The PMS5003ST has a Humidity and Temperature sensor built in so i was thinking, is it possible to model the PM2.5 / PM10 based on the humidity and temperature readings so that it avoids getting huge readouts in foggy conditions? (like a humidity compensation?)
2. How people avoid 'wrong' readouts during foggy conditions with these particle sensors?

Comment: As this question does not seem to be anything to do with the Arduino, I'll migrate it to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange for you.

Comment: the PMS5003ST link is invalid

Comment: maybe you could heat the air that is being measured

Comment: Just speculating: Maybe there exists a  membrane which lets through air but not water drops above a certain size.